# Correct positioning of multiple significance labels on dodged groups in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I want to present two groups with their development over time in a boxplot, and add labels of significance for each group (intra-group comparisons). I have a working example using `ggpubr::stat_compare_means`, but I am unable to correctly position the two geoms.

I have attempted `position = position_dodge(width=0.5)`and several other positional elements, but for some reasons they wont move at all. My desired output would have each label set horizontally shifted to be over each groups box, and vertically adjusted to not overlap.

Example code using `diamonds`:

```
df <- filter(diamonds, color == "J" | color == "E")
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = cut, y = price, fill = color)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test",data = filter(df, color == "J"), comparisons = list(c("Fair","Good"),c("Fair","Very Good"),c("Fair","Premium"))) +
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test",data = filter(df, color == "E"), comparisons = list(c("Fair","Good"),c("Fair","Very Good"),c("Fair","Premium")))
```

[image: Example image]

Comment: Maybe this could be taken as a good incentive to get away from multiple inter- and intragroup testing with multiple significance bars in the plot? Visualisations don't necessarily benefit from overpopulation with significance bars... If you really want to present so many significance values, I think you will fare much better with a table.

Comment: While that might be true, I still need to produce the desired graphic. There will only be two sets of labels, for intergroup comparisons over the x-axis from a reference group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I really don't think this is a good idea for visualisation - here is a solution. If you use ggpubr, stay in the ggpubr syntax. And use faceting for subgrouping.

P.S. Try a table instead.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

mydf <- filter(diamonds, color == "J" | color == "E")

comparisons <- list(c("Fair", "Good"), c("Fair", "Very Good"), c("Fair", "Premium"))

ggboxplot(mydf, x = "cut", y = "price", facet.by = "color") +
  stat_compare_means(
    method = "t.test", ref.group = "Fair", label = "p.format",
    comparisons = comparisons
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, and your input regarding multiple labels. 
I have two questions regarding your solution; is it possible to do this in ggplot-syntax, and would it be possible to avoid faceting, even though it might cause clutter?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible without massive hacking. And I don't think without facets - all examples in the vignette and on tutorials on subgroups include faceting. It is not really designed for this type of stuff.