# Manually plotting significance relations between sub-groups on ggplot2 barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr, significance

I've been trying to plot manually labelled significance bars for a subset of groups on a `ggplot2` barplot using `ggsignif` or `ggpubr` without much luck. The data is something like the following MWE:

```R
set.seed(3)
## create data
df <- data.frame(activity = rep(c("Flying", "Jumping"), 3),
                 mean = rep(rnorm(6, 50, 25)),
                 group = c(rep("Ecuador", 2),
                           rep("Peru", 2),
                           rep("Brazil", 2)))
## plot it
ggplot(df, aes(x = activity, y = mean, fill = group)) +
    geom_bar(position = position_dodge(0.9), stat = "identity",
             width = 0.9, colour = "black", size = 0.1) +
    xlab("Activity") + ylab("Mean")
```

[image: Example plot]
Where I'd like to manually specify significance labels, say between Brazil/Ecuador" on "Flying", and Ecuador/Peru on "Jumping". Does anyone know how to properly deal with this kind of data, for example with `ggsignif`? And is there a way to refer to each bar by name, rather than try to work out its x-axis position?

Comment: I would recommend tables if you are showing significances on many subgroups. If you really really need to plot the bars, I think @dc37 showed a great way. You can also use ggpubr, but for subgroups you need to stay in ggpubr syntax, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772321/correct-positioning-of-multiple-significance-labels-in-ggplot/60773902#60773902.

Comment: I agree it would be too confusing with many subgroups, although in my case I have a lot of subgroups, but only want to show significance for a subset. But the solution from @dc37 looks good for my purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know on which barchart you want to add your significance labels, you can do:

```r
library(ggsignif)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = activity, y = mean, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(0.9), stat = "identity",
           width = 0.9, colour = "black", size = 0.1) +
  xlab("Activity") + ylab("Mean")+
  geom_signif(y_position = c(60,50), xmin = c(0.7,2), xmax = c(1,2.3),
              annotation=c("**", "***"), tip_length=0)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Thanks, how do you work out the correct values for xmin though to make sure they're centred? (In the real plot I have extra groups).

Comment: You're welcome ;). For placing your xmin and xmax values, you have to think that each x axis labels is counted starting from 1. So the center of Flying is 1 and the center of Jumping is 2. So, then you can play around to get the appropriate labeling.