# Compare values by x-axis with geom_signif

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

With `ggpubr::geom_signif` it is easy to add comparisons for different values or groups on the X-axis.
Here is an example

```
ex = data.frame(time = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                effect = runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 100),
                group = c("blue","red"))

comparisons = list(
  c(1,2),
  c(1,3),
  c(1,4),
  c(1,5)
)

ex %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = effect, group = group)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(geom = "line") +
  geom_signif(comparisons = comparisons, step_increase = 0.1)
```

[image: Example of X-wise comparisons]

How would one go about performing comparisons within each time-point instead?
My desired output has the data presented the same way, but with P-values for the difference between the groups at each time point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct positioning of multiple significance labels in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772321/correct-positioning-of-multiple-significance-labels-in-ggplot)

Comment: as per answer to your very own question from a year ago, regarding the same principle - A year ago there was no ggpubr solution to this. This might have changed. Or, if not, maybe you would feel it might warrant a feature request. They might put it fairly low priority though. The downvote is not mine, but I do understand it

Answer (score 0):

It's at the least doubtful if calculation of all those p-values is justified, or correct. Anyways - One way to show what you want is to have group as x and facet by time

With your type of analysis, you seem to treat each timepoint as independent (which they are not, they are correlated), and the visual equivalent is to separate them to individual facets and not link them with a line.

```
comparisons = list(
  c(1,2))

ex %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = group, y = effect)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(geom = "line") +
facet_wrap(~time) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = comparisons, step_increase = 0.1)
```

Comment: I absolutely agree that for correlated data like this you need to take that into consideration, which is done through a separate model. That being said, I'd still like to avoid facetting.

Comment: @mhovd I was thinking that this question reminded me of something I answered last year. I found it - and it's not only a duplicate, but the OP was you! lol

Comment: Hah, what a coincidence! I found the solution to my other question, which was using `step_increase` in `geom_signif`. However, that question was concerned with the layout and preventing overlap, not comparing by a group or value on the X-axis :)