# Adjusting position of stat_pvalue_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am trying to adjust the position of comparison bars with stat_pvalue_manual.
TL/DR How do I fix plot p1?

This is what I'm working with:

```
df <- ToothGrowth
grp<-rep(c("a","b","c"), 10)
df$grp <- grp
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
stat.test_len <- df %>%
  group_by(dose) %>%
  dunn_test(len ~ supp)
stat.test_len <- stat.test_len %>% add_xy_position()
stat.test_len
# A tibble: 3 x 14
#   dose .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic       p   p.adj p.adj.signif y.position
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>
#1   0.5 len   OJ     VC        10    10   -2.31   0.0210  0.0210  *                  24.2
#2   1   len   OJ     VC        10    10   -2.91   0.00357 0.00357 **                 30.0
#3   2   len   OJ     VC        10    10    0.0379 0.970   0.970   ns                 36.6
# ... with 3 more variables: groups <named list>, xmin <dbl>, xmax <dbl>
```

Now when I use it for ggplot, the xy positions don't adjust properly.

```
library(ggpubr)
p1 <- ggerrorplot(df, x = "dose", y = "len", 
            desc_stat = "mean_sd", color = "supp")+
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test_len, label = "p.adj.signif",
                     tip.length = 0,
                     hide.ns = TRUE)
```

Somehow it still works when I use faceted plot.

```
p2 <- ggboxplot(df, x = "supp", y = "len", color = "supp")+
  facet_wrap(~dose)+
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test_len, label = "p.adj.signif",
                     tip.length = 0,
                     hide.ns = TRUE)
```

I added the extra column "grp" because that's what I need in my final plot. y-axis will be multiple doses. color will be 3 different values for grp. I need to plot stats for comparison between grp at each dose. Using the OG ToothGrowth df so that there are significant p-values to work with.

How do I fix plot p1?

Comment: I don't think ggpubr is designed for this. see also for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772321/correct-positioning-of-multiple-significance-labels-in-ggplot I think your facet solution is the most straight forward.